# Is $P=\{x\in\mathbb{R}_+: n\mapsto\lfloor nx\rfloor\text{ is a p.r.f.}\}$ closed under addition?

Tags: logic, computability

The question comes from the notion of a [computable number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number). If we consider the set $$R=\{x\in\mathbb{R}_{\geqslant 0}: n\mapsto\lfloor nx\rfloor\text{ is recursive}\}$$ (with $n$ running over nonnegative integers, and the [conventional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_recursive_function) definition of a recursive function), then $R\cup(-R)$ forms a *field* (correct me if I'm wrong). I'm wondering what exactly breaks down if we restrict ourselves to $n\mapsto\lfloor nx\rfloor$ being [primitive recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function). If we call the resulting set $P$ (as in the title), is $P$ closed under addition (that is, does $x,y\in P\implies x+y\in P$)?

(A side note. The inclusion $P\subset R$ is proper; if $x=0.\overline{a_1a_2a_3\ldots}_2$ is the binary fraction representation of $x\in(0,1)$, then $a_n=\lfloor 2^n x\rfloor-2\lfloor 2^{n-1}x\rfloor$; thus, if $n\mapsto\lfloor nx\rfloor$ is [primitive] recursive, then so is $n\mapsto a_n$. And there are recursive functions $\mathbb{N}\to\{0,1\}$ which are not primitive recursive.)

I'm pretty sure the answer is negative, but I feel lost for seeing a proof. (Is there a way to attack it by relating $\lfloor nx\rfloor-n\lfloor x\rfloor$ to the indicator function of some non-recursive set?..) *I'm a beginner in this field, but I'm aware of the basics.* (It may well be a duplicate of another question; please indicate if it is.)

Comment: Apologies, I really slipped off here. I deleted my previous comments.

Comment: @Manlio: I've deleted mine, and edited the question (to prevent a potential confusion).